# Bat's input type and string

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am new to bat. My question is why this block of code does **not** print something like "name is 0001".

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,124) do (
    set aaa=000%%i
    echo name is %aaa%
)
```

It only gives me back as `name is`.

So can anyone explain how this happens? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about `call echo name is %^aaa%`?

Comment: As an example of the `Call` method, try this as a single line batch file, `@(For /L %%A In (1 1 124)Do @Set "aaa=000%%A"&Call Echo(name is %%aaa:~-3%%)&Pause`

Comment: @Compo Thx for your help! I am not clear what the `@Set` and `@Call` means. Can you type this in the answer so it can be displayed in a more clearly way? Again, thx a lot.

Comment: @Boooooooooms  `@` is to inhibit the commands themselves from showing on the cmd/batch window. As for other commands, you can open `cmd` first, and type `command /?` to read their manual, for example `set /?` and `call /?`.

Comment: @Tiw, thx! Got it!

Comment: @Boooooooooms, there is no `@Call`! and all you need to do, is to open up notepad, paste in those `82` characters, and save as > all files > `example.cmd`. Then double-click on the file to run it and see it in action!

Comment: @Compo, I got it! Really cool codes! Character as `&` and `@` are still new to me.

Comment: @Boooooooooms: You should know that the _standard way_ to solve this problem is via Delayed Expansion as described in the linked answer (and a ton more answers about the same topic): insert `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at beginning and use `echo name is !aaa!`. The `call` method is an unintended and officialy undocumented behavior ("trick") that works by chance... It is also much slower than delayed expansion.